# create database and table from given input

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i want to create a database and a table from the given input and at the same time check if database and table already exist when i run code below only database is created and not the table. can someone help me please.

```
<HTML>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
Project No.:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
Question: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

If(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $projno = $_POST['name'];
    $question = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['proj'] = $projno;
    $_SESSION['QA'] = $question;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$checkdb = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".$projno;
if($conn->query($checkdb)===TRUE)
{
    $dbname = $projno;
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($tableExists = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE ".$question) > 0){

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
}

}
else{
// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE " . $projno;
if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
}
}
?>
```

Hi here is my updated code. thanks for youre help it works already . but iam having another problem having this error.
Error creating You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '23992550' at line 1. It doesn't accept number input for database name. hope you can help me again. thanks in advance

```
<HTML>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
Project No.:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
Question: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

If(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $projno = $_POST['name'];
    $question = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['proj'] = $projno;
    $_SESSION['QA'] = $question;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$checkdb = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".$projno;
if($conn->query($checkdb)===True)
{
    $conn->query("USE $projno");
    if ($conn->query("DESCRIBE " . $question))
{
    //Table exist
        header('location:exp.php');
}
else
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$question."(LIST VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
       header('location:exp.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }
}


}
   else
    {
        echo "Error creating " . $conn->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should never put anything like that in production as it is badly designed (multiple databases for a single form), susceptible to SQL injection (hacker friendly), contains no validations whatsoever.  Even if you don't get hacked and fix it so it works, it will become unmanageable very very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to select database by re-establishing connection:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
...
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

But it doesn't work, because you're actually getting the same variable. You should reuse original connection instead:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
...
// After CREATE DATABASE
$conn->query("USE $dbname");
```

or

```
// ...
$conn->select_db($dbname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DESCRIBE` keyword to check table exist or not.

Use below code.

```
if ($conn->query("DESCRIBE " . $question))
{
    //Table exist
    echo "Table exist";
}
else
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50),
            reg_date TIMESTAMP
            )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have test it in my local and its work fine. @Jan Aranas

Comment: yes  this one works in checking tables.. thanks used this one too sadly i cant give two check :( sorry . so i gave the check to the answer which corrected my redundancy in creating connection to database.. thanks for the answer though.